# Can we add tag searches to post sorting criteria on the profile page?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

The questions, answers, and favorites sections currently provide the capability to sort by certain criteria. However, can we add a search capability in these sections for tags, strings, etc.?

People would have answered 100's and 1000's of questions and hence it would be easier for them to access them later.

Ex: For a repeat question, I just want to find the link to a similar question I answered earlier.

Answer (score 2):

We already support most or all of this in the form of advanced search queues. For example, `user:me` will search only your posts; use `is:question` to limit the results to questions or `is:answer` to search only answers. `infavorites:mine` will search only your favorites. Putting the name of a tag in square brackets (e.g. `[c#]`) will search for questions that have that tag.

All of these are documented in the "Advanced Search Tips" drop-down on the [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page. And I hear rumors that a horde of well-trained unicorns is working on [a page that contains even more information on advanced search techniques to eventually be added to the Help Center on all sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

So I suppose your feature request here is to add search textboxes to the profile interface? I suppose that could be workable. It would certainly make these searches more discoverable.

However, my concern would be over-complicating and crowding the UI. Not just in terms of the space taken up, but also the fact that we would then have *multiple* search boxes on a single page—not the hallmark of usability.